# Unit testing Express controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unit-testing, es6-modules

Been working on this for days now. Finally breaking over and asking for help.

When I have the server running and make API calls, things work as expected.

Now I am trying to unit test the controller and running into issues. Hoping for some clarification as I am obviously missing something vital.

classCodesController.js (base minimum code. I have commented out everything but this in my testing without joy)

```
import { classCodeModel } from '../models/classCodeModel.js';
import { asyncHandler } from '../utils/asyncHandler.js';

const getAll = async (req, res, next) => {
    const record_set = [];

    res.status(400).json({
        status: 'success',
        length: record_set.length,
        data: record_set
    });
};

export {
    getAll
};
```

classCodesController.test.js

```
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import { describe, it, mock } from 'node:test';
import mockHttp from 'node-mocks-http';
import { getAll } from '../../src/controllers/classCodeControllerv1.js';
import { classCodeModel } from '../../src/models/classCodeModel.js';

describe('getAll: return JSON', () => {
        it('should return array of two records as JSON', { timeout: 5000 }, async () => {
            const req = mockHttp.createRequest();
            const res = mockHttp.createResponse();
            const next = mock.fn();

            await getAll(req, res, next);

            assert.deepStrictEqual(res.statusCode, 400);
            assert.deepStrictEqual(res.json(body), { status: 'success', length: 0, data: [] });
    });
});
```

When called, the status code does not change and the json is not returned.

I have tried passing my own res object which worked when I unit tested middleware modules.

```
            const res = {
                body: '',
                data: {},
                message: undefined,
                statusCode: 100, // noramlly defaults to 200
                statusText: '', // normally 'OK'
                headers: {},
                config: {},
                reqeust: {},
                send: mock.fn(),
                status: mock.fn(c => {
                    this.statusCode = c;
                    return this;
                }),
                json: mock.fn(d => {
                    this.message = d;
                    console.log('json d: ', d);
                })
            }
```

The console.log in json function outputs the controller submitted data, but message is still undefined (TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'message')) when it gets to the test and the statusCode has not changed.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should `await getAllCodes(req, res, next);` be `await getAll(req, res, next);` ? You also have an extra curly bracket here `import { getAll } }`

Comment: @jQueeny You would be correct but those errors are from reducing the code for posting. Code acts as described. Updated the code.

Comment: Try using `res` instead of `this`

Comment: @phil Changing this to res returns res.StatusCode to what is preset in the res object and re.message returns empty, but undefined (again preset in object).

Comment: One note of reference. If you want to use this in a function, you must use function(){} not anonymous function structure. Still didn't change the result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http), you should use `res._getJSONData()` to get the response JSON data. Below is a working example:

`getAll.js`:

```js
const getAll = async (req, res) => {
    const record_set = [];
    res.status(400).json({
        status: 'success',
        length: record_set.length,
        data: record_set,
    });
};

export { getAll };
```

`getAll.test.js`:

```js
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import { describe, it, mock } from 'node:test';
import mockHttp from 'node-mocks-http';
import { getAll } from './getAll.js';

describe('getAll: return JSON', () => {
    it('should return array of two records as JSON', async () => {
        const req = mockHttp.createRequest();
        const res = mockHttp.createResponse();
        const next = mock.fn();

        await getAll(req, res, next);

        assert.deepStrictEqual(res.statusCode, 400);
        assert.deepStrictEqual(res._getJSONData(), { status: 'success', length: 0, data: [] });
    });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
$ node --test ./getAll.test.js
▶ getAll: return JSON
  ✔ should return array of two records as JSON (1.215ms)
▶ getAll: return JSON (2.3065ms)

ℹ tests 1
ℹ suites 1
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 80.1445
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "77646756",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Node version:

```bash
$ nvm ls

  * 21.4.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    18.19.0
    16.20.2
```

Comment: Thank you. Currently I am using 20.9.0 LTS and node-mocks-http 1.14.0. I have constrains on sticking to LTS versions. How did you get the res.statusCode to pass? I still get 200 !== 400 where 200 is the default in node-mocks-http response and SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input for the JSON test. Could this be a version issue?

Comment: Using nvm I updated to 21.4.0, still getting the same responses.

Comment: ```
const json_data = res._getJSONData();
console.log('JSON Data: ', json_data);
```
is returning the Syntax Error even without the assertion call.
The console.log never happens.
assert.ok('res._isEndCalled');
assert.ok('res._isJSON');
assert.ok('res._isUTF8');
All pass

Comment: After further troubleshooting, it was another function in my code that was causing the issue. @Lin Du's answer was correct. Thanks Lin Du.